# How to retrieve url from mysql to nightmare .goto funtion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nightmare

I have some URLs in a MySql database. Those URLs I want to pass one after another to `nightmare.goto()` and then evaluate the website.

Once it is finished, I want another URL to pass in to `nightmare.goto()` so that I can evaluate all the URLs from the database. How can I do it?

For example:

```
 nightmare
     .goto('firsturl.com')
     .wait(2000)
```

evaluation is done..
then again

```
nightmare
       .goto('secondurl.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about promise iteration?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); //there are a lot of promise libs 

var sites = ['https://www.google.it/', 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://github.com'];

Promise.each(sites, (url)=>{
   return nightmare
         .goto(url)
         .wait(2000);
 });
```

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. Then I tried this function.,, async.eachSeries(MyArry, function(MyUrl, callback){ nigthmare.goto(MyUrl).wait(200) then it only works for one url whereas I want all MyUrl should visit one after another. Any further help please.

Comment: Problem solved by:   async.eachSeries(MyArry, load, function(err) {
                     console.log('done!');
                 });
                 // Iterating through each url and calling load function

         function load(MyUrl, callback) {
            callback()
        }